# Mysql my.cnf for linux 4core/8thread 64gb memory

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I just moved server and am working on the my.cnf to optimize it for my pc, if someone can give a review on it, as the site is loading very slow on initial connect. In Pingdom, it shows it as "WAIT", and it starts loading site after about 8 seconds. 
Here's my My.cnf

```
[mysqld]
datadir="/var/lib/mysql"
socket="/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
user=mysql

open_files_limit=26672
innodb_file_per_table=1
symbolic-links=0
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
tmp_table_size                 = 1G
key_buffer_size = 2G
max_heap_table_size            = 2G
query_cache_size               = 2G
max_connections                = 500
thread_cache_size              = 5G
table_definition_cache = 2G
max_allowed_packet=64M
table_cache=2G
max_connect_errors = 10
binlog_cache_size = 2G
read_buffer_size = 2G
read_rnd_buffer_size = 5G
sort_buffer_size = 2G
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 3G
join_buffer_size = 3G
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 4G
thread_cache_size = 2G
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 4G
thread_concurrency = 8

query_cache_size = 1G
query_cache_limit = 10G

innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 1G
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_file_io_threads = 4
innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_log_files_in_group = 3
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120


myisam_sort_buffer_size=2G

[mysqld_safe]
log="/var/log/mysqld.log"
log-error="/var/log/mysqld.error.log"

[myisamchk]


sort_buffer_size = 5M

read_buffer = 50M

write_buffer = 50M
```

All advice/ criticism are welcomed, i am an amatuer in this and have made this by reading up blogs and other resources.

Comment: Off topic. Not a programming question. You could try the DBA site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use Percona's Configuration Wizard for MySQL:
https://tools.percona.com/wizard

And to check if you really need:

1) MyISAM engine;
2) query cache;